# Python Fast Input Output Using Buffer Competitive Programming

Tags: python, performance, io

I have seen people using buffer in different languages for fast input/output in Online Judges. For example this http://www.spoj.pl/problems/INTEST/ is done with C like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define size 50000

int main (void){
unsigned int n=0,k,t;
char buff[size];
unsigned int divisible=0;
int block_read=0;
int j;
t=0;
scanf("%lu %lu\n",&t,&k);

while(t){
    block_read =fread(buff,1,size,stdin);
    for(j=0;j<block_read;j++){
        if(buff[j]=='\n'){
            t--;
            if(n%k==0){
                divisible++;
            }
            n=0;
        }
        else{
            n = n*10 + (buff[j] - '0');
        }
    }
}

printf("%d",divisible);
return 0;
```

How can this be done with python?

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
file = sys.stdin
size = 50000
t = 0
while(t != 0)
    block_read = file.read(size)
    ...
...
```

Most probably this will not increase performance though – Python is interpreted language, so you basically want to spend as much time in native code (standard library input/parsing routines in this case) as possible.

TL;DR either use built-in routines to parse integers or get some sort of 3rd party library which is optimized for speed.

Comment: 3rd party libraries will not work in online judges. Thanx for this though.

Answer (score 0):

I tried solving this one in Python 3 and couldn't get it to work no matter how I tried reading the input.  I then switched to running it under Python 2.5 so I could use

```
import psyco
psyco.full()
```

After making that change I was able to get it to work by simply reading input from `sys.stdin` one line at a time in a for loop.  I read the first line using `raw_input()` and parsed the values of `n` and `k`, then used the following loop to read the remainder of the input.

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    count += not int(line) % k
```